# Как получить список всех папок которые содержат аудио файлы

Tags: java, android

Как получить список всех папок которые содержат аудио файлы?

Comment: Выполнить поиск аудиофалов и вывести папки в которых эти файлы нашлись.

Answer (score 1):

Если быстро то так :

```
 public static void getFiles(String pathName) {
        File file = new File(pathName);
        File[] fileList = file.listFiles();
        for (File currentFile : fileList) {
            if(currentFile.isDirectory()) {
                getFiles(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            if(currentFile.isFile()) {
                if(currentFile.getAbsolutePath().contains(".mp3")) {
                    System.out.println(currentFile.getParent().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Но тут по сто раз будет выводиться папку.

UPD : 
Вот вам для любого расширения файла
П.С. сделано как скажут очень гадко(использовал метку + break);

```
public static void getFiles(String pathName, String fileExtension ) {
    File file = new File(pathName);
    File[] fileList = file.listFiles();

    point : for (File currentFile : fileList) {
        if (currentFile.isDirectory()) {
            getFiles(currentFile.getAbsolutePath(), fileExtension);
        } else if (currentFile.isFile()) {
            if(currentFile.getAbsolutePath().contains(fileExtension)) {
                System.out.println(currentFile.getParent().toString());
                break point;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DuosDuo, сделал второй вариант для любого расширения